# How can I use "typeof" to get the type from a generic class?

Tags: typescript

When I declare a generic class `A` in `a.js`, and export it.Then, I don't know how to declare the variable of class `A` in `b.js`.

Code below:
`a.js`:

```js
export let A = function<K extends { value: number }>(DEFAULT_NUMBER){
    return class A<T> {
    test(obj: T, num: number): K {
        return obj.diff(DEFAULT_NUMBER, num);
    };
    };
}(
    // DEFAULT_NUMBER
    1000
);
```

`b.js`

```js
import { A } from "a.js";

class B {
    diff(): { value: number } {
        // ...
    }
};

let a: InstanceType<typeof A<B>> = new A();

a.test(new B(), 50);
```

Simpler code below:

```js
let A = class<T> {};

class B {};

let a: InstanceType<typeof A<B>>; // throw a syntax error
// or
let a: InstanceType<(typeof A)<B>>; // throw a syntax error
// or
let a: InstanceType<typeof (A<B>)>; // throw a syntax error
// or
let a: (InstanceType<typeof A>)<B>; // throw a syntax error
// or
let a: InstanceType<typeof A>; // correct, but the type of a is `A<unknown>`
```

How should I declare the variable `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking a lot about this question in the two days, finally, i found the answer, code below:

```js
type ReplaceItemTypeOf<Target extends any[], NewType, OldType = unknown> = {
    // for each item of the array
    [Key in keyof Target]: (
        // if the type is matched, return NewTypeNewType, otherwise return the origin type of the item value
        OldType extends Target[Key] ? NewType : Target[Key]
    );
};

type NonAnyType<T> = (T & 1 extends 1 ? 1 : 0) extends 1 ? T : never;

type InstanceTypeOfGenericRef<GenericRef extends new(...args: any) => any, Type> = {
    // for each property
    [Key in keyof InstanceType<GenericRef>]: (
        // if the type is matched unknown type or empty object type
        {} extends (
            // if property is a method
            InstanceType<GenericRef>[Key] extends (...args: any) => infer Result ?
                // if type of Result is any return never, otherwise return the origin type of Result
                NonAnyType<Result> :
                // if type of the property value is any return never, otherwise return the origin type of the property value
                NonAnyType<InstanceType<GenericRef>[Key]>
        ) ?
            (
                // if property is a method, and type has matched
                InstanceType<GenericRef>[Key] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer Result ?
                    // return a new method interface which has replaced argument types
                    (...args: ReplaceItemTypeOf<Args, Type>) => Type :
                    // if not a method, return Type
                    Type
            ) :
            (
                // if property is a method and type has not matched
                InstanceType<GenericRef>[Key] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer Result ?
                    // return a new method interface which has replaced argument types
                    (...args: ReplaceItemTypeOf<Args, Type>) => Result :
                    // return origin type of the property value
                    InstanceType<GenericRef>[Key]
            )
    );
};

let A = class A<T> {
    set(value: T): T {
        return value;
    }
}

let a: InstanceTypeOfGenericRef<typeof A, string>;

a.set("123");
```

A screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is syntax for this. There is certainly no syntax for getting the return type of a generic function with specific type arguments.

One way to do it is to go through a dummy function:

```
let A = class<T> {};

class B {};

let aHelper = () => new A<B>();
let a: ReturnType<typeof aHelper>;
```

Comment: I don't want to declare any variables except `a`, like `aHelper`, what should i do ? thank you very much

Comment: @Michael_Lee let the compiler infer the type `let a = new A<B>`.

Comment: Only a declaration, no initialization, what should i do? because, i will use the type with a class property, like ` class C { xx: InstanceType<typeof A>; }`;

Comment: declare a type first:    
`type aHelper<K, T extends new(...args: any[]) => any> = T<K> extends new<K>(...args: any[]) => infer X ? T<K> : number;` 
     then     
`let a: aHelper<string, typeof A>;`
        
      but `Type 'T' is not generic`, how can i convert a normal type `T` to a generic type?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there should be no type definitions (for example `value: number`) in any **.js**-file. Rather, they should belong to **.ts**-files (TypeScript as opposed to JavaScript).

In **TypeScript**, if you have a generic class defined like follows:

```
export class A<T extends { something: number }> {
    useSomething(obj: T) {
        console.log(obj.something)
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
class B {
    something: number
}
const a = new A<B>()
a.useSomething(new B())
```